# widevine adaptive streaming in Android 4.0

Tags: android

I can't find a way to change bit rate of a file that is being played. In Widevine API for iPhone there is WV_SelectBitRateTrack, which selects the bit rate corresponding to the specified track number. I'm looking for something similar for Android 4.0.

Thanks and regards,

ElDae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a public link for this, but as far as I know the Widevine Android API doesn't support manually setting the bit rate (although, as you write, it is supported by the iOS API).

The playback bit rate should be adaptive, based on the strength of your connection.

Comment: I confirm that behavior - the bit rate is selected automatically